# convert json array to aadata format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

my currrent array format is not being interpreted by datatables aaData format as im passing column values:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "startDate": "09/08/2010 12:00:00 AM",
            "endDate": "13/08/2010 12:00:00 AM",
            "runDate": "16/08/2010 12:00:00 AM",
            "clientId": "40272",
            "clientType": "C",
            "plannerName": "Adrian Mcfly",
            "plannerRegion": "s1",
            "contact": "Vera chaniqua",
            "email": " ",
            "interviewDate": "09/08/2010 12:00:00 AM"
        },
    ]
}
```

how do i remove the column id and display just the values so that i can be read by datatables as a ajax call?

Comment: `jsonobject.aaData[0]` ?

Comment: if thats a json object (which looks like it) then you could do something like `delete aaData[0][clientId]` in js

Comment: btw ur missing  a `]` at the end :)

Comment: btw you should remove the comma at the end

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT 8/29/2012**

As of 1.9 you can disable having to have a root JSON property.

```
"sAjaxDataProp": "",
```

This is likely what you will get with most JSON serializers.

Or customize it

```
"sAjaxDataProp": "myData",
```

In datatables 1.8 you can format your json like this:

```
{
        "aaData": [
            {
                "DT_RowClass": "",
                "description": "",             
                "pkgLineTree": {
                    "treeId": {
                        "name": "Jacksonville"
                    }
                }              
            },
            {
                "DT_RowClass": "",
                "description": "",       
                "pkgLineTree": {
                    "treeId": {
                        "name": "Jacksonville"
                    }
                }         
            }

        ]
    }
```

And in your datatable properties add this

```
"aoColumns": [    
        {
            "mDataProp": "pkgLineTree.treeId.name"
        },  
        {
            "mDataProp": "shortname"
        },
        {
            "mDataProp": "description"
        }, 
        {
            "mDataProp": "lineStatus"
        }
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically what you've got there is a JSON representation of an array of *objects* (with properties *startDate*, *endDate*, ...), but what you need is an array of *arrays* of strings.

I'm assuming you are doing server-side processing, so if you don't want to change the server code, you can get just in the middle of the fetching process and modify the data right before giving it to the callback of datatables.

What I do next is just going through each object in the fetched data and create the array of values:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
            /* --- Here is where we massage the data --- */
            /* if the variable "json" is just a string (I forgot) then evaluate it first into an object (download a json library)*/
            var aaData=[];
            $.each(json, function(index, object) {
                var aData=[];
                $.each(object, function(key, value) { 
                    aData.push(value); //be careful here, you might put things in the wrong column 
                });
                aaData.push(aData);
            }); 
            /* --- And after we're done, we give the correctly formatted data to datatables --- */  /* --- if "json" was a string and not an object, then stringify aaData first (object to json notation, download a library) --- */
            fnCallback(aaData)
        } );
    }
} );
```

} );

Hope it works!

Comment: You don't need array of strings in 1.8.  Allan allows objects now.  Check my post for update.

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets instead of opening/closing curly braces { and }. For details, see my answer to this question: [datatables and json formatting error with php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501479/699091)