# datatables and json formatting error with php

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables

HI im having a little difficulty with dataTables and php. I'm echoing out json in the format below:

{"iTotalRecords":10,"iTotalDisplayRecords":10,"aaData":[[ "1", "15","1","long description long description long description long description"," 2012-02-25 00:00:00"],[ "1", "15","1","long description long description long description long description"," 2012-02-25 00:18:59"] ...   ]    }

Which inst working with my dataTable, However after validating the above in jsonlint.com/, i get the well formated version below:

```
   {
            "iTotalRecords": 10,
            "iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
            "aaData": [
                [
                    "1",
                    "15",
                    "1",
                    "long description long description long description long description",
                    "2012-02-25 00:18:59"
                ],
        ...

            ]
        }
```

When I put this in a txt file it loads just fine. I also noticed that adding a line break in the "long description" part, it also doesn't work even with the one above. My guess is that the line break is messing with the format of the json, but how can I avoid this in my php script since everything is being word wrapped? I've tried \n in my echo code but it doesnt seem to create a newline.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.  Can you clarify?  Are you just looking for echo "<pre>" so that the information looks more readable?

Comment: May I suggest clarifying a bit what exactly isn't working? JSON itself is correct, I suppose; did you try parsing it and giving to datatables the result (JS array) instead?

Comment: I am simply echoing out the json, but dataTables isnt able to use this as its json source, for some reason I keep getting a "json formatting error". I am using 'sAjaxSource':'json.php' as the source. When I delete the "long description" part of the Json, it works. I think that when this part starts on a new line, it messes with the Json and dataTables isnt able to load it.

Comment: Did you try to sent a JSON with 'Content-Type: application/json'?

Comment: Sorry, new to jquery and and haven't done any ajax. Where exactly would I put this?

Comment: There seemed to be an issue with one of my database values, it was starting on a new line, which cause the format of the json to be incorrect. Fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemsed to be an issue with one of my database values, it was starting on a new line, which cause the format of the json to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The opening and closing curly braces `{` and `}` are not acceptable to DataTables. My guess is, it's considered an object rather than an array. Try this:

Use the following php function to create your JSON array:

```
$this->arrayJSON = $this->arrayPHPToJS($myArray);

public function arrayPHPToJS($phpArray) { 
    if (is_null($phpArray)) return 'null'; 
    if (is_string($phpArray)) return "'" . $phpArray . "'"; 
    if (self::is_assoc($phpArray)) { 
        $a=array(); 
        foreach ($phpArray as $key => $val ) 
            $a[]=self::arrayPHPtoJS($val); 
        return "[" . implode ( ', ', $a ) . "]"; 
    } 
    if (is_array($phpArray)) { 
        $a=array(); 
        foreach ($phpArray as $val ) 
            $a[]=self::arrayPHPtoJS($val); 
        return "[" . implode ( ', ', $a ) . "]"; 
    } 
    return json_encode($phpArray); 
}
```

Use this array in JS script in your view (make sure there's no html escaping):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsArray = <?php echo $arrayJSON; ?>;

    $(function(){
        var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable( {
            "aaData": jsArray,
            ....
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds more like the number of columns set up in table/datatables doesn't match number of items in your json array