# Jquery Bootstrap Datatable sorting not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$("#tbllistOPDetails").DataTable({
     "scrollY": scrollY,
     "scrollX": true,
     "paging": true,
     "scrollCollapse": true,
     "searching": false,
     "orderCellsTop": true,
     "info": true,
 });
```

[image]

The above is my Data table code, the sorting is not working properly.

Comment: Age column have not worked properly with sorting. I am right.

Comment: Issue not with Age column in table @Singh

Comment: Where you face issue? Can you show your browser console ? @Devasish

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$("#tbllistOPDetails").DataTable({
    aaSorting": [],
    "bSorting": false,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bDestroy": false,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "sScrollY": "scrollY", //Put height if you want
    "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "ID", "sType": 'numeric'  },
                    { "sTitle": "Name" },
                    { "sTitle": "Age", "sType": 'numeric' },
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
                    { "sTitle": "Preference" }
                ],

    "aaData": DataName
});
```

You have to tell data table about column type. So it will sort correct.

Comment: what is the purpose of "aaData": DataName

Comment: For information about aaData. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5105731/3081659

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation on the website https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/ it is very easy to implement this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables.numericComma.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [
                { "type": "numeric-comma", targets: 3 }
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

example https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_manual

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. This is help to get `desc` order of age. You can change to `asc` order.

Find more details at https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

```
$("#tbllistOPDetails").DataTable({               
            "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
$("#tbllistOPDetails").DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "searching": false,
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "info": true,
});
```

Just remove `"scrollY": scrollY,` from script

Comment: Where you face issue? @Devasish